# dynamic selection for linear interpolation

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, excel-formula

I have a function, which i called InterpolLinear

```
Function InterpolLinear(x, xvalues, yvalues)

    x1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xvalues, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x, xvalues, 1))

    x2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xvalues, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x, xvalues, 1) + 1)

    y1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xvalues, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(y, xvalues, 1))

    y2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xvalues, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(y, xvalues, 1) + 1)

    InterpolLinear = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)

EndFunction
```

I want the function to automatically select all the x values and all the y values, without having to adjust it manually. I can have 10 x and y values, or 100. The function is working ok, but i have to adjust the selection manually.

I took 2 screenshots.

[image: Correct Selection]

[image: what i want to avoid]

Comment: look at `range.end(xlDown)`, im presuming, you just want to enter `fx(d1,e1,f1)` ?

Comment: i'm really new into this, but i'll try to explain. i want to enter fx(d1, column F, column E). columns F and E should expand (or contract) if i have values from row 1 to 5, or 1 to 10 (expanding my selection)

Comment: well in that case, your range would be an input, so you'd have `fx(a,r1 as range,r2 as range)` as your declaration, and you'd use `r1.end(xlDown).row` to find the last cell, then build from there `range(r1.cells(1,1),r1.cells(r1.end(xlDown).row,1))` and `range(r2.cells(1,1),r2.cells(r2.end(xlDown).row,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define two *named ranges* which adjust dynamically. Add a named range, say `x_values` and define it by

```
=$E$1:INDEX($E:$E;MATCH(1000000;$E:$E;1))
```

Do the same for `y_values`, changing the references to column F. Then

```
=LinInterp(D1;x_values;y_values)
```

*note, your images used the function `LinInterp` and your code uses the function `InterpolLinear`, so just make sure you're consistent*

---

Also, you can assign your variables more simply, for example:

```
 x1 = xvalues.Cells(Application.Match(x, xvalues, 1),1).Value
```

Comment: i just don't get how to define my named range... can you be more specific?

Comment: @T.Almeida -- On the ribbon go to *Formulas>Define Name*, then give it a name `x_values` and use the formula I provided above, then repeat the process for another named range called `y_values`

Comment: oh thanks, now i see it! how can i change the row where the selection starts? for example, if i want the values to start in row 3 and not in row 1.

Comment: @T.Almeida, Just change `$E$1` to `$E:$3`.

Comment: does that not give a problem of they can only exist in E and F?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav It depends on whether you want the user to have more visibility of the exact range which is being used or not. In most cases you'd want the user to be able to see what the ranges are without needing to look at the VBA code and possible even debug it. I nearly always prefer this style.

Comment: sorry but the selection doesn't change. it just selects the entire column, and locks cell E1

Comment: surely, you could name them at the end of the code.  No worries.  Now the user defines the name, rather than selecting.

Comment: @T.Almeida, I just tested it -- it's working fine for me (but I just noticed the typo I made in the comment earlier). Make sure the reference is `=$E$3:INDEX($E:$E;MATCH(1000000;$E:$E;1))`

Comment: @CallumDA http://imgur.com/t4j3q56 http://imgur.com/sPKTN8v here it is (but starting in row 1)

Comment: @T.Almeida What's the problem? Do you want to change it to row 3? Or do you think it's selecting the whole column?

Comment: @CallumDA where it starts it's not a problem (i understand how to change it from row 1 to row 3) - it's the end. to correctly use my function, and having in mind the two screenshots that i've posted in the previous coment, my selection should end in row 6 - where my values end.
if my values end in column 50, i want it to select from row (1 or 3, it's ok) - to row 50.

Comment: @T.Almeida -- You can't see where a *dynamic named range* ends in the normal way. Click on cell `A1`, for example,  then where it says `A1` in the top left corner drop down, type `x_values` (or whichever dynamic range you'd like to see) and it will give you the visual representation of your dynamic range. Let me know if you can't do that

Comment: @CallumDA i see, and yes, the selection is correct. now i think my function is not working correctly, the problem might be another thing!